# What does `balance.available` event in Stripe mean?

Tags: stripe-payments

Can anybody explain to me what `balance.available` event in Stripe means. We are receiving this event to our webhook and our application is not configured to handle such event.

I have searched around Stripe documentation but cannot find a clear explanation of what this event is for. Here's an example:

```
{
    "object":
    {
        "object": "balance",
        "available": [
        {
            "currency": "gbp",
            "amount": 1999,
            "source_types":
            {
                "card": 1999
            }
        }],
        "livemode": false,
        "pending": [
        {
            "currency": "gbp",
            "amount": 0,
            "source_types":
            {
                "card": 0
            }
        }]
    },
    "previous_attributes": null
}
```

Comment: The event will be triggered whenever a positive balance change occurs (on the available balance). After the 7 days of waiting for the money, you will receive this event once the pending amount is credited to the available amount

Comment: But balance of which account? The merchant account (e.g. my company account which receives payment) or any specific customer/card?

Comment: The merchant account | Balance -> available is what you can payout to your bank account immediatly

Comment: I see. Thank you. Should I close this question?

Comment: Perhaps this will be useful for some people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a list of webhook events:

https://stripe.com/docs/api/php#event_types

For this event:
balance.available
describes a balance
Occurs whenever your Stripe balance has been updated (e.g., when a charge is available to be paid out). By default, Stripe automatically transfers funds in your balance to your bank account on a daily basis.

Comment: Link no longer works, documentation at stripe is still missing 4 years later.

Comment: @boatcoder The documentation does exist, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-balance.available) for the Stripe API's full list of webhook events:

> balance.available is a Balance [object]
>
> Occurs whenever your Stripe balance has been updated (e.g., when a charge is available to be paid out). By default, Stripe automatically transfers funds in your balance to your bank account on a daily basis.

[The documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/api/balance/balance_object) for the `balance` object states that it refers to:

> Funds that are available to be transferred or paid out, whether automatically by Stripe or explicitly via the Transfers API or Payouts API. The available balance for each currency and payment type can be found in the source_types property.

Therefore, `balance.available` is a webhook event that notifies you when you have funds in your Stripe merchant account ready to be paid out, and you can expect it to trigger either once a day or however often you've set your payout schedule to in your Stripe account. In other words, it's the webhook event that makes everything else worth it. ;) Presumably the event exists to make it possible for developers to query and log their Stripe earnings. If you don't need to access this information programmatically then you can safely ignore the `balance.available` event.